# jQuery .hover() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I have is as the title says. It works on all divs but one!

```
 $(".complete-wrapper-1").hide();
var panelHH = $(".file-select-wrapper").innerHeight;
$(".files-button").hover(function(){
    $(".complete-wrapper-1").show();
});

$(".complete-wrapper-1").hover(function(){
    $(".file-select-wrapper").stop(1).show().height(0).animate({height: panelHH},500);
}, function(){
    $(".file-select-wrapper").stop(1).animate({height: 0},500, function(){
        $(this).hide();  
    });
});
```

Edit: html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href="osframe.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href="appframe.class.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href="icons.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href="start-menu.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href="menus.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="anos_api_buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="applications.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game_api.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ApplicationLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MultiPane.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="front-end.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryFileTree.js"></script>
  <noscript>You browser does not support javascript of it may disabled.</noscript>
 </head>
    
    
 <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <div id = "frameAsWhole">
   <div class ="item-frame">
                <div class = "box1">
        <div class = "infoPane">
        </div>
    
                    <div class = "area-frame">
                        <div class = "desktop-box">
                            <div class = 'info-dropdown'></div>
                            <table class = "table">
                            </table>
                            <div class ="search-r-wrapper">
                                <div class = "search-part">
                                    Search
                                </div>
                                <div class = "recent-part">
                                    Recent Apps
                                </div>
                                <div class = "search-results">

                                </div>
                                <div class = "recent-results">

                                </div>
                                <div class = "downard-arrow"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "file-select-wrapper">
                                <div class = "file-select">
                                    <div class = "folder-select-wrapper">
                                        <div class = "desktop-folder" class = "folder-icon fisize">
                                            <div class="folder-text-side folder-text-side-1">Desktop</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "folder-select-wrapper">
                                        <div class = "documents-folder" class = "folder-icon fisize">
                                            <div class="folder-text-side folder-text-side-2">Documents</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class = "folder-select-wrapper">
                                        <div class = "images-folder" class = "folder-icon fisize">
                                            <div class="folder-text-side folder-text-side-3">Images/Videos</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class = "folder-select-wrapper">
                                        <div class = "music-folder" class = "folder-icon fisize">
                                            <div class="folder-text-side folder-text-side-4">Music</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "folder-select-wrapper">
                                        <div class = "applications-folder" class = "folder-icon fisize">
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "downard-arrow"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "complete-wrapper-1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "taskbar-wrap">
                        <div class = "taskbar">
                            <div class = "files-button">
                                
                            </div>
                            <table>
                                <tr class = "taskbar-items">

                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class = "search-wrapper">
                                <input type="textarea" class ="search-bar">
                                </input>
                                <div class = "computer-search">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS not included
Lines 1 to 5 work but nothing after that does. The rest works if .complete-wrapper-1 is not the div I want .hover(); to work on. Any ideas?

Comment: Your HTML please?

Comment: The code hides it because it should not be open be default, then when you hover over the folder icon it shows the wrapper div which opens the folder list and keeps it open as long as you hover over the wrapper which is just an invisible div right on top of the folder list div.

Comment: Also once wrapper is open it stays open.

Comment: What happens if you remove the code for animation and just use $(".file-select-wrapper").show(); and $(".file-select-wrapper").hide();

Comment: A jsfiddle would definitely be helpful here

Comment: @Taleeb still doesn't work, I have even console.log() a random string right under the animation code and it does not log

Comment: @Taleeb Also, just for test, I did the exact same thing except with the '.time' div i.e. hid it and got it to open when the file icon div was hovered and when you hover over the '.time' div it will open the file list. So it is a problem with the wrapper div.

Comment: I found the problem! My javascript code was executing too much. I had a setInterval() running that was unnecessary.

Comment: Nope actually! Still not working.

Comment: Is it possible that my code has too much to run? I have about 437 lines of javascript code @Taleeb

Comment: I doubt that - but then I'm not an expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code nearly works but not 100%. The problem was to do with z-index in my css code and was blocking the element from the mouse so that it would not have anything to run the event. Kind of like if I had x-ray google and tried to crab someones heart with my hand, it obviously wouldn't work.